# Can't boot after upgrading to 18.04 from 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, upgrade

I just upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 17.04 to 18.04. I tried to reboot it, but it just showed flashing again and again and never come to Desktop. Anyone can help with this?

Comment: What version did you upgrade to? 18.04 or 18.10?

Comment: Not sure if it will help but when it's stuck at booting, press Ctrl+alt+F1. This should bring up a terminal. You can login there. Then you can copy the log files and post them here.

Answer (score 1):

Try going into recovery mode:

1. Get to the GRUB menu (you may need to press escape or space or something...I'm not intimately familiar with the defaults in Ubuntu).
2. Select the recovery option.

If that boots, then you can post the logs and we can figure out what's going on. If that doesn't boot either, you might still get more output there, which should help us debug what's going on.